# Create a ggplot graph with inferno instead of viridis color palette

Tags: r, ggplot2, viridis, inferno

I have the dataset below

```
data<-structure(list(new_cat = c("animals", "art", "books", "business", 
"celebrity", "colleges", "fashion", "food", "games", "geography", 
"history", "language", "medicine", "military", "misc", "movies", 
"music", "mythology", "nature", "philosophy", "politics", "publications", 
"religion", "royalty", "science", "shakespeare", "sports", "technology", 
"theater", "tv", "usa", "work", "world"), jobzone = c(-0.0105999996885657, 
0.0111999996006489, 0.00490000005811453, 0.0187999997287989, 
-0.000300000014249235, 0.0274999998509884, 0.00579999992623925, 
-0.00689999992027879, -0.00600000005215406, 0.0175999999046326, 
0.0071000000461936, 0.0094999996945262, 0.0187999997287989, 0.0094999996945262, 
0.0082999998703599, -0.00989999994635582, -0.000600000028498471, 
-0.0197000000625849, -0.0130000002682209, 0.0131000000983477, 
0.0156999994069338, 0.0136000001803041, 0.0199999995529652, 0.0137999998405576, 
0.0175999999046326, 0.00529999984428287, 0.00680000009015203, 
-0.00039999998989515, -0.00659999996423721, -0.00680000009015203, 
0.0153000000864267, 0.0304000005125999, 0.00430000014603138), 
    gender = c(-0.0249000005424023, -0.0082999998703599, -0.0182000007480383, 
    -0.0500999987125397, -0.0205000005662441, -0.0712999999523163, 
    0.0619000010192394, 0.0103000001981854, -0.0723000019788742, 
    -0.0729999989271164, -0.0612999983131886, -0.0227000005543232, 
    -0.0148999998345971, -0.102300003170967, -0.0243999995291233, 
    -0.0296000000089407, -0.0288999993354082, -0.0187999997287989, 
    -0.0226000007241964, -0.0654999986290932, -0.0843999981880188, 
    -0.0606000013649464, -0.0348000004887581, -0.0149999996647239, 
    -0.0860999971628189, -0.00630000000819564, -0.130799993872643, 
    -0.0683000013232231, 0.00609999988228083, -0.0230999998748302, 
    -0.0538999997079372, -0.0693999975919724, -0.0511999987065792
    ), n = c(31041, 26811, 62019, 19413, 14448, 6873, 11994, 
    43848, 9183, 54375, 41538, 28536, 21783, 24579, 58488, 51846, 
    52392, 10995, 15987, 3276, 42849, 5931, 25839, 8367, 31488, 
    6699, 36417, 16908, 18468, 31074, 55770, 4524, 24174), score = c(0.216984122991562, 
    -0.0226046573370695, 1.9715895652771, -0.441630125045776, 
    -0.722849607467651, -1.15190041065216, -0.861845076084137, 
    0.942377388477325, -1.02106118202209, 1.53863060474396, 0.811538100242615, 
    0.0750999823212624, -0.307392448186874, -0.149025976657867, 
    1.77159249782562, 1.39538705348969, 1.42631268501282, -0.918428778648376, 
    -0.635680079460144, -1.35563588142395, 0.885793626308441, 
    -1.20525562763214, -0.0776591002941132, -1.06727969646454, 
    0.242302373051643, -1.16175580024719, 0.521482765674591, 
    -0.583514273166656, -0.495155304670334, 0.218853250145912, 
    1.61764395236969, -1.28494870662689, -0.171965315937996), 
    avgmoney = c(808.570007324219, 1032.0400390625, 965.710021972656, 
    802.549987792969, 778.710021972656, 885, 802.539978027344, 
    743.010009765625, 700.030029296875, 906.200012207031, 937.690002441406, 
    846.72998046875, 885.049987792969, 911.710021972656, 806.02001953125, 
    921.090026855469, 887.030029296875, 906.450012207031, 898.289978027344, 
    1108.31994628906, 909.799987792969, 895.460021972656, 871.179992675781, 
    928.330017089844, 964.830017089844, 934.710021972656, 764.440002441406, 
    830.330017089844, 1027.80004882812, 806.690002441406, 811.619995117188, 
    840.530029296875, 916.119995117188)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -33L))
```

I'd like the size of the dots to represent the size of each category (variable `n`), and the color of the dots to be based on the value of each category (variable `avgmoney`).

I'd like to try this with both viridis and inferno color schemes, with the label "Average Money" in the graph.  The x-axis is variable `jobzone` and the y-axis is variable `gender`.

I did it with `viridis` with but not with `inferno`

```
    # Load required libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
library(colourvalues)
# Create the scatter plot
p <- ggplot(bourdieuclassgender, aes(x = jobzone, y = gender, size = n, color = avgmoney)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(3, 12)) +
  scale_color_viridis(name = "Average Money") +
  labs(x = "Correlation: Job Zone and Contestant Responses",
       y = "Correlation: Female Contestant and Response") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "right")

# Print the plot
print(p)
```

Comment: `scale_color_viridis_c(option = "inferno")`? ggplot2 v3.0.0 from 2018 added viridis scales to ggplot2. "magma" (or "A"); "inferno" (or "B"); "plasma" (or "C"); "viridis" (or "D"); "cividis" (or "E"); "rocket" (or "F"); "mako" (or "G"); "turbo" (or "H").   https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#scales-and-guides-3-0-0

Comment: yes that works thanks